# Does the managed WinRT API include a way to compute an MD5 hash?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

How can I compute MD5 in a Metro Style app that is written in C#?

Comment: what does the style have to do with the MD5??

Comment: and what does MD5 have to do with Cryptography?

Comment: Because it uses a different subset of the .NET BCL, see new tag winrt

Comment: Now it gets downvotes?! Clearly people don't understand. The runtime of a Metro-Style app uses a different set of the .NET framework than your usual .NET Framework. I.e. in the documentation there is no trace of a security cryptography namespace!

Comment: For your own sake, elaborate i bit further. I think there's a good question hidden in that one-liner. +1 for a potentially good and valuable question.

Comment: Metro style apps are sandboxed and use a different profile of .net. So the usual crypto classes might not be available (I didn't check). So being a metro app can certainly be relevant. And MD5 is certainly crypto, just broken crypto.

Comment: Here you can find the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299142/how-to-generate-md5-hash-code-for-my-winrt-app-using-c

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of information on the locations of various namespaces for Metro at the [Metro style app reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229578).

I'm not sure about MD5, but the the hashing stuff for SHA is in [Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241423.aspx)

Obviously we don't know if you really need MD5, but if you don't (i.e. you're not talking to something else that expects MD5) then don't - it's often the go-to hashing for people just because it's more *famous*, but others are often better for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx), apparently this ends up in a Windows namespace. I suspect the *HashAlgorithmProvider* does what you need, but I couldn't test yet.