# How to generate MD5 hash code for my WinRT app using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I'm creating a MetroStyle app and I want to generate a MD5 code for my string. So far I've used this:

```
    public static string ComputeMD5(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            var alg = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("MD5");
            IBuffer buff = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(str, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            var hashed = alg.HashData(buff);
            var res = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, hashed);
            return res;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but it throws an exception of type `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the following error message:

`No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070459)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: The line before `return res;` I mean `var res = ...`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

OK. I've found how to do this. Here's the final code:

```
    public static string ComputeMD5(string str)
    {
        var alg = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
        IBuffer buff = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(str, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        var hashed = alg.HashData(buff);
        var res = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: You may want to explain what you changed and why.

Comment: Well instead of using `ConvertBinaryToString` function to convert the hashed binary array I should've used the `EncodeToHexString` function to convert the array to the *Hex* string. That is the only thing I changed.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori Didnt get the refrence for HashAlgorithmProvider

Comment: It's `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.HashAlgorithmProvider`. Just add `using Windows.Security.Cryptography`

Comment: On Windows 8.1 (Universal Apps) The class static Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.HashAlgorithmNames contains names of algorithms.

Comment: I would replace "MD5" to [HashAlgorithmNames.Md5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmnames.md5.aspx).

Comment: What a bloody pain in the arse that was. Thanks loads for the solution.

Comment: Hi, if i want to compare with the password in my Database i need to perform the same thing to encrypt and then tuck the result to compare ? Thanks!

Comment: This code worked great for me for generating Sha256 hash, just changed the algorithm. Thanks.