# Can't import the HashAlgorithmProviders nor the CryptographicBuffer Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, md5

I'm trying to create an MD hash using the following code I found from [Alireza Noori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299142/how-to-generate-md5-hash-code-for-my-winrt-app-using-c). But I cannot import both the `HashAlgorithmProviders` nor the `CryptographicBuffer` Classes. Even when I try to manually add them using the following packages:

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography; 
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core; 
using Windows.Storage;
```

How come I cannot import these classes do they need to be installed?

Comment: Using MD5 in general is not good security, instead use a currently secure cryptographic hash such as SHA-256.

Comment: I have to use md5 because I'm using a marvel API

Comment: I do agree with @zaph, you may want to consider a more secure function other than MD5.

Answer (score 0):

It's apparent your using statements are incorrect, they should look something like:

```
using System.Windows.Security.Cryptography; // CryptographicBuffer Class package 
using System.Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core; // HashAlgorithmProviders Class package
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
```

You have to manually either of these .dlll frameworks, depending on your .Net Framework version
Goto:

Project >> Add Reference >> Framework >> Add System.Web.ApplicationServices +
 (.Net 4.5+)

or

Project >> Add Reference >> Framework >> Add System.Web.Security - (.Net 4.0)

Comment: That is not working for me, instead the errors jumped to .Security

Comment: Please elaborate on what the current error message saying.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/LQgtjAqjThosb9W72 This is the error i'm getting