# Windows 8 VB MD5 hash

Tags: windows, vb.net, md5

Hello i am looking for a md5 hash function for windows 8 (metro app)

I have been looking for this in google (and other search engines) but there is nothing for windows 8 , most of them are about win 7 (or older)

thank you any way :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute MD5 on Metro Style app in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297627/compute-md5-on-metro-style-app-in-c-sharp) – this should be applicable to VB.NET as well, apart from minor syntactic differences.

Comment: But it is not even answered !!!

I can find nowere any type of hashes on windows 8 !!

"Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates" has no hash properties :S

Comment: If doing this for security, be aware that MD5 isn't very secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find MD5 but i find for SHA256 here is some sample if you are interested in ;)

```
Function sha512(Key As String)
    Dim hash As String
    Dim strAlgName As String = "SHA512"
    Dim objAlgProv As HashAlgorithmProvider = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName)
    Dim objHash As CryptographicHash = objAlgProv.CreateHash()
    Dim buffMsg1 As IBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(Key, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE)
    objHash.Append(buffMsg1)
    Dim buffHash1 As IBuffer = objHash.GetValueAndReset()
    Dim strHash1 As String = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffHash1)
    hash = strHash1
    Return hash
End Function
```